# Mongolite and R

Tags: r, mongolite

I have the code below, why it is not working? Thanks.

```
library(mongolite)
library(jsonlite)

id <- c('35325073','35325078')

id_list_JSON <- toJSON(id)

test3 <- m1$find('{"_id": {"$in": id_list_JSON}}', fields = '{"_id" : 1, "f.fid" : 1, "ud" : 1}')
```

> Error: Invalid JSON object: {"_id": {"$in": id_list_JSON}}

Comment: JSON is just a string. R will not parse it and replace what LOOKS like a variable name with the variable's value.  so `{.... id_list_JSON}}` is invalid, because that's a bare string within the json, not an R variable.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the comments. What would be a solution then?

Comment: never done R, but just do a string building: `'{"_id....:' + id_list_json + '}}'`, but you have to make SURE that you're building syntactically correct json. if you don't do it exactly 100% correctly, it'll just be another syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Marc B is correct in that you have to build the string to use the values contained in `id_list_JSON`.

In R you can use `paste0` to do this

```
test3 <- m1$find(paste0('{"_id": {"$in": ', id_list_JSON, '}}'), 
                 fields = '{"_id" : 1, "f.fid" : 1, "ud" : 1}')
```

Where the `paste0` line gives

```
paste0('{"_id": {"$in": ', id_list_JSON, '}}')

# "{\"_id\": {\"$in\": [\"35325073\",\"35325078\"]}}"
```

Which should then work in your query.